# how to use orderBy() in onSnapshot() so I can order the documents on the basis of the timestamp?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, snapshot

So basically please tell me how I should implement the orderBy() function of firestore in onSnapshot() in React. Please help me, guys. I really need your help. If your answering my question please share this code with the orderBy() function implement in it. Here is my code -

```
onSnapshot(collection(db, "messages"), (snapshot) => {
setMessages(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id})))
 })
```

and I have returned this

```
<div className="chat-app">
    {messages && messages.map((msg) => {
      return (
        <div key={msg.id} className="message">
          <img className="img" src={msg.image}></img>
          <div className="msg">{msg.message}</div>
        </div> 
      )
    } )}
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of a "simple" `CollectionReference`, you can pass a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.query.md#query_class) to the [`onSnaphot()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#onsnapshot) Function, as follows. You'll find more details in the [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data).

```
import { ..., collection, query, orderBy} from "firebase/firestore";  

const q = query(collection(db, "messages"), orderBy("xyz"));
onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
    setMessages(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })))
})
```

---

Note: Actually a `CollectionReference` extends a `Query`.

Comment: hello, I have implemented your code but now I don't know why but I am not able to see the data from the documents in my React website. It's just blank

Comment: Can you check the size of the `QuerySnapshot` with `snapshot.size`?

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: `onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.size);
})`